# Import data into database and show it on html table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to create a view in laravel that has a function to import an excel file into the database and show it in a table inside a view.

I created a controller and it imports the excel data in database but fails to show it in view.

Please Help solve my issue.

Many Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

## Dian

I am using laravel 5.5 and maatwebsite excel

```
public function importFileIntoDB(Request $request){
        if($request->hasFile('sample_file')){
            $path = $request->file('sample_file')->getRealPath();  
            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();
            if($data->count()){
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $arr[] = ['name' => $value->name, 'details' => $value->details];
                }

                if(!empty($arr)){
                    \DB::table('products')->insert($arr);
                    dd('Insert Record successfully.');
                }
            }
        }

        return back()->with($arr);   
    }
```

this is my view

```
@extends('frontpage')

@section('title', 'Dashboard')

@section('content_header')
    <h1>Upload File From Excel Into Database</h1>
@stop

@section('content')
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="container">   
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="padding:12px 0px;font-size:25px;"><strong>Test - import export csv or excel file into database example</strong></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">

          @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {{ Session::get('success') }}
          </div>
        @endif

        @if ($message = Session::get('error'))
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ Session::get('error') }}
          </div>
        @endif

        <h3>Import File Form:</h3>
        <form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 20px;" action="{{ URL::to('importExcel') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <input type="file" name="import_file" />
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <br/>

          <button class="btn btn-primary">Import CSV or Excel File</button>

        </form>
        <br/>


          <h3>Import File From Database:</h3>
          <div style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 20px;">     
            <a href="{{ url('downloadExcel/xls') }}"><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Download Excel xls</button></a>
          <a href="{{ url('downloadExcel/xlsx') }}"><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Download Excel xlsx</button></a>
          <a href="{{ url('downloadExcel/csv') }}"><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Download CSV</button></a>
          </div>


            <h3>Table Import List </h3>
          <div style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 20px;" > 
              print_r($arr->count());
              @if(!empty($arr))
               <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-reflow">
                  @foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
                          <tr>
                              <th ><strong> {{ $key }}: </strong></th>
                              <td>  {{ $value }} <td>
                          </tr>
                  @endforeach
              </table>
              @endif
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@stop

@section('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin_custom.css">
@stop

@section('js')
    <script> console.log('Hi! this is frontpage'); </script>
@stop
```

Comment: "but failed when show it in view." Any Errors?

Comment: Hi linktoahref, i don't have any error, but the html table I expected not created, as if there's no row in array. have any Idea ?  something I missed in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As conveyed by @gbalduzzi you need to return the data to the view as

```
return back()->with(['arr' => $arr]);
```

and access in your view as

```
@if(session()->has('arr'))
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-reflow">
@php $arr = session('arr'); @endphp
@foreach($arr as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <th ><strong> {{ $value['name'] }}: </strong></th>
        <td>{{ $value['details'] }} <td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</table>
@endif
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses)

Comment: hi linktoahref,

Comment: hi linktoahref, I follow your code, but I got error. undefined  arr. have any idea?

Comment: Can you do a `dd(session('arr'))` in your view and show what you get? and please try with the updated code

Comment: Hi linktoahref, I did dd(session('arr')) and has value. but when I called it in  view still error undefined arr... please help

Comment: Can you post what you get while doing `dd(session('arr'))`

Comment: hi linktoahref, dd(session('arr')) in my view return data array. I got different error 'htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'. I've search through google  but has no luck. have any idea? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please try with the new code

Comment: linktoahref . thank you, thank you so much  for your help. thank you for your kindness , the issue has been solve.. thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return back()->with($arr);
```

with

```
return back()->with(['arr' => $arr]);
return back()->with('arr', $arr); // Should be equivalent
return back()->compact($arr); // Should be equivalent
```

The `with` method doesn't accept only a single value: you need to specify an array, a key and a value or use the `compact` method

Comment: Hi gbaldduzzi, Thanks for the answer, I've changed the return back with compact. but i sitll can't see the html table in my webpage.  have you seen my view? is that something I missed or mistake I made? thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, if you don't get any error but the table is empty it means that your `$arr` is empty. Can you add a `dd($arr)` before calling the `return back()->...` inside your controller?